# Firebase Android: onDataChange() event always executed in Main UI Thread?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In an Android application using Firebase, I need to execute long operations in background once Firebase returns a query answer.  E.g.:

```
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot data) {
         dosomething very long. . .
         then call a callback forUI thread
   }
```

I know that firebase execute the query in asynchronous mode but the `onDataChange()` method seems to be always executed in the main UI Thread, even if I try to call the query in a custom background Thread.

Does anyone knows how to manage this use case?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The callbacks for your Firebase listeners are indeed executed on the main UI thread.

If you need to do heavy operations in a callback, spin up an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and do the work there. The `AsyncTask.doInBackground()` method executes on a different thread, so it won't block the Android UI. But `AsyncTask. onPostExecute()` executes on the main thread again, so you can update your UI views from there.

If you're using Cloud Firestore, see [Abhriya Roy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59358464) on how to get the callbacks on a background thread.

Comment: ok it's clearer now. I will launch an async task directly in the onDataChange() method, and this task will execute the callback UI Listener at the end.

Comment: Is there a way to set the thread where you want to get the callback action back?

Comment: Frank, do you have that idea in mind? to be able to select the thread you want to return the Firebase callback?

Comment: Thanks I didnt know the listeners happened in the main UI thread and it was driving me crazy

Comment: I'm not a fan of AsyncTasks and I usually prefer something like this --> https://github.com/CodingDoug/white-label-event-app/commit/917ff279febce1977635226fe9181cc1ff099656

Comment: @wonsuc That answer applies to Cloud Firestore, while this question is about Realtime Database. As far as I know, the option to specify the callback thread is still the same there.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen My apologies, I was confused about OP's question with Firestore, only `AsyncTask` should be changed to `RxJava` or Kotlin's `Coroutine`.

Answer (score 6):

Might be a little too late to the party, but if you want `Firebase` to return call backs on the background thread, you can use the `BACKGROUND_EXECUTOR` from `com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Executors.BACKGROUND_EXECUTOR` like

```
.addOnCompleteListener(BACKGROUND_EXECUTOR, OnCompleteListener<Void> {
   ...
}
```

There are other executers as well like -

```
DEFAULT_CALLBACK_EXECUTOR
DIRECT_EXECUTOR
```

Comment: Does this apply to Realtime Database too? That's what the question was about (Firestore didn't even exist back when this was asked).