# Why does thread changed to Main thread in callback?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I am developing an android app using the Kotlin and RxJava.

I developed In-App billing using the android latest API.

But the library only support async callback.

So I make a code like:

```
private fun consumePlayStore(consumeParams: ConsumeParams, secKey: String, purchase: Purchase): Single<Pair<String, Purchase>> {
    return Single.create<Pair<String, Purchase>> { emitter ->
        Log.d("TEST", "[Billing] consumePlayStore") // IO Thread

        // Google InApp Library call
        playStoreBillingClient?.consumeAsync(consumeParams) { result, _ ->

            // In here, thread is Main!!! Why!!!
            Log.d("TEST", "[Billing] consumePlayStore - response")  // Main Thread
        }
    }
}


fun consume() {

    verifyCompletable.andThen(consumePlayStore())
            .flatMap(otherJob)
            .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
            .observeOn(uiScheduler)
            .subscribe()


}
```

I don't know why the thread is changed in the callback?

Somebody tell me why?

And how can I solve this problem???

or better design???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason and a solution.

First, the reason is that the Google InApp library only supports the Main thread.

> All methods are supposed to be called from the Ui thread and all the asynchronous callbacks will be returned on the Ui thread as well.

refer: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.html?hl=ko

So I fixed my code like:

```
fun consume() {
    verifyCompletable.subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
            .observeOn(uiScheduler)
            .andThen(consumePlayStore())
            .observeOn(ioScheduler)
            .flatMap(otherJob)
            .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
            .observeOn(uiScheduler)
            .subscribe()
}
```

This code works fine, but I don't know that this is a beautiful solution.

Schedulers look like very complicated...

Comment: There is no need to subscribeOn twice, the chain can only have one starting point.