# NetworkOnMainThreadException using Firebase Storage in IntentService

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download a file using the Firebase Storage but I get this error even though I'm calling it in onHandleIntent.

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case ACTION_DOWNLOAD:
                ArrayList<Talk> talks = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_TALKS);
                if (talks == null) return;
                handleDownload(talks);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the place where I'm trying to copy the file locally.

```
private void handleDownload(ArrayList<Talk> talks) {
    for (final Talk talk : talks) {
        FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                   .getReferenceFromUrl(talk.getUrl())
                   .getStream()
                   .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StreamDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(StreamDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        try {
                            File file = new File(DEFAULT_TALKS_DIR, "name_" + UUID.randomUUID());
                            IOUtils.copyLarge(taskSnapshot.getStream(), new FileOutputStream(file));

                            talk.setPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
                            TalksDatabase.getInstance(context).insertTalk(talk);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
}
```

The full exception:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.blockGuardOnNetwork(Platform.java:300)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:741)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:136)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:50)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource.read(HttpConnection.java:418)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:371)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$zza.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1792)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769)
    at eu.long1.jwnotes.services.ReceiveService$4.onSuccess(ReceiveService.java:206)
    at eu.long1.jwnotes.services.ReceiveService$4.onSuccess(ReceiveService.java:200)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$1.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$1.zzk(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.zze$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

**UPDATE:**
You guys were right the listener are called from the main thread. I just found this using @AlexShutov

```
public zzbtz(@Nullable Executor var1) {
        this.zzbFQ = var1;
        if(this.zzbFQ == null) {
            this.mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        } else {
            this.mHandler = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35777599

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Did you read the post? I'm calling from onHandleIntent() witch is called on a background thread. @MikeM.

Comment: @Henry i think this's not a possible duplicate.

Comment: Doesn't matter where you call it from. The listeners are invoked on the main thread.

Comment: @MikeM. So why do we have AsyncTasks and IntentServices?

Comment: So you can do your own work on separate threads. Firebase already does its work asynchronously, and it delivers results on the main thread.

Comment: Can you give me some docs that prove what you're talking and that using an ServiceIntent to receive data will call the listeners on MainThread and not as intended on a background thread? @MikeM.

Comment: `onSuccess(` is being called on UI thread.

Comment: give me some docs or prove your answer in some way because it's not logic for me @VladMatvienko

Comment: It took me some time to find an obvious thing (that it is called on ui thread) in the documentation, which should be done by you, not by me. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageTask#addOnSuccessListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener<?%20super%20TResult>)

Comment: I see but how is this possible since I'm using an IntentService?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Firebase calls .onSuccess() callback method on a main thread for convenient use with UI. You try copying from stream into file, which involves network operation. Try make copy in background too.

Comment: I'll try but it doesn't make sense. I'm using an IntentService.

Comment: set breakpoint in callback and see on which thread it is called in debug mode first. You make calls from loop on background, callback can be executed on main thread for ease of updating UI

Comment: I found it! Thanks!