# Where will Firebase onDataChange() run in this example?

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, executorservice

I know the `onDataChange()` in Firebase for let say `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is running on [Android Main Ui thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777400/firebase-android-ondatachange-event-always-executed-in-main-ui-thread).

I Wanted to understand what will happen if I run this code inside the `ExecutorService`:

```
runInBackground(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    ref.child("SOME_KEY")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent
                    (new ValueEventListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                             //.. do some work on Ui Thread or not??
                         }

                         @Override
                         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                             notificationRunning = false;
                         }
                     }
                    );
}
});
}
```

Will the onDataChange() still run on the Main Ui Thread in Android?
And here´s the `ExecutorService` runner

```
/**
 * Submits request to be executed in background.
 * Threads submitted will be executed synchronously.
 *
 * @param runnable
 */
private void runInBackground(final Runnable runnable) {
    mBackgroundExecutor.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                runnable.run();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And the `ExecutorService`

```
mBackgroundExecutor = Executors
        .newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
                Thread thread = new Thread(runnable,
                        "Background executor service for OneSignal");
                thread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
                thread.setDaemon(true);
                return thread;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listener callbacks always run on the main/UI thread.  The thread that was used to add the listener does not affect the callback thread.  You can confirm this by adding a log statement to your callback that outputs the thread name:

```
Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Thread=" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```